# Pregunta sobre relaciones nulas laravel

Tags: laravel, relaciones

Buen día, alguien sabe si en laravel al hacer una relación entre ejemplo 2 modelos (usuarios, departamentos) y por x motivo el usuario no tenga departamento, sea posible que en lugar de retornar null retorne algún caracter o cadena ejemplo "Sin departamento ". Igual es una pregunta media estupida
Gracias .

Comment: Lee [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) la sección llamada **default models** eso resuelve tu problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claro que es posible.

En tu modelo de Apartment puedes tener lo siguiente:

```js
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Apartment')->withDefault([
        'name' => 'Sin apartamento',
    ]);
}
```

Para que de esa manera cuando accedas de la manera `$user->apartment-name` regrese la cadena que le pongas.

O puedes crear un mutador en el modelo `User`:

```js
//En caso de que tu relación sea que User hasOne('Apartment')

public function getApartmentAttribute()
 {
    if($this->apartment) { //Verifica la relación que tienes de usuario a apartamento
      return $this->apartment->number; //O cualquier otra cosa que desees si sí existe la relación
    } else {
      return "Sin apartamento";
    }
 }
 
 //En caso de que tu relación sea que User hasMany('Apartment')

public function getApartmentAttribute()
 {
    if($this->apartments->count()) { //Verifica que el arreglo de apartamentos tenga elementos
      return $this->apartments->first()->number; //O cualquier otra cosa que desees si sí existe la relación
    } else {
      return "Sin apartamentos";
    }
 }
```

Con eso tendrás para resolver tu problema.

Saludos, bienvenido a StackOverflow :)